# Yo keystone not working for Ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, keystonejs, yo

I am trying to deploy a keystone app using the MEAN stack. I have installed all other packages. After that I tried to follow these steps mentioned here:

http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/

but when I tried to execute the command

```
$ yo keystone
```

It says "yo command is not found"

Comment: Have you installed Yeoman? It' not mentioned on thegetting-started page. `npm install -g yo`

Comment: yes I have installed yeoman.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have Node installed and npm working.

Then, you need to have yo installed with:

```
npm i yo -g
```

You need to make sure that you have the Node's `bin` directory in the PATH.

And now you can finally use:

```
yo keystone
```

but not before that because yo is not installed with Node automatically and Node is not installed with Ubuntu automatically either.

For more info see:

- https://nodejs.org/en/download/
- https://docs.npmjs.com/
- http://yeoman.io/

Comment: Thanks rsp. As I already mentioned. It was not working as I had to create a symbolic link for nodejs as node so that "node" command is recognized by the system in stead of "nodejs".  see it here http://truthyfalsey.com/yeoman-working-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help but I found a help here:

http://truthyfalsey.com/yeoman-working-ubuntu/

I followed the steps and it is working. I hope this was all about environment variable. Now the issue is fixed and now I can run :

$ yo keystone